# How do I read two numeric inputs in the same line, separated by a space in Java?

Tags: java, user-input

For Example :
`22 42`

These are two digit numbers separated by a space. Kindly suggest any Java function which I can use to read it as two separate numbers.

Comment: Read from console or from file or from JSON or XML or ... ?

Comment: put the code that you try..

Answer (score 0):

You could just read the line of input and split it into an array?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)
String userInput = sc.nextLine();
int [] inputSplit = userInput.split("\\s+");
```

Read more on `\\s+` and `String` patterns [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Read more on the `Scanner` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use split method to parse integer from a line.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter integer separated by spaces: ");
String input = sc.nextLine();
String[] numberString = input.split("\\s+");
```

Now you have a `String` array `numberString` you can convert it to integer array and then use it -

```
for(int i = 0;i < numberString.length;i++)
{
   //assuming you have an int array numbers[]
   numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberString[i]);
}
```

Hope it will help.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Scanner#nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) and assign the values as

```
String input = "22 44";
Scanner s = new Scanner(input);

if (s.hasNextInt()) {
    a = s.nextInt();
}
if (s.hasNextInt()) {
    b = s.nextInt();
}

s.close();
```

If you're expecting multiple `int`s in your input, use a `while` loop instead.

```
String input = "22 44 55 66";
Scanner s = new Scanner(input);

List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (s.hasNextInt()) {
    ints.add(s.nextInt());
}

s.close();

System.out.println("How many ints? " + ints.size()); // 4
```

To read the numbers from a *console* instead, create a `Scanner` on top of `System`'s *input* `InputStream`. And, don't forget to call `Scanner#close()` when done.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter Numbers");
String in = sc.nextLine();
String [] in1 = in.split("\\s+");
System.out.println("Numbers");
for( String n: in1)
{System.out.println(n);
}
```

Output:

Enter Numbers
1 2 3 4 5
Numbers
1
2
3
4
5

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

String s1 = sc.next();
String s2 = sc.nextLine();

s2 = s2.replace(" ","");

int num1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
```

Hope this was helpful.